# SSH port forwarding on MacOS X

Tags: networking, ssh, mysql

I know there are quite a few tutorials about this, but I can not get it to work on my machine.

So I have a MySQL database running on:

```
Server: dbhost.net
Name: mydbuser
PW: mydbuserpwd
Port: 3306
```

This database is reachable via an SSH connection as this:

```
Server: dbhost.net
Name: mysshuser
PW: using my ssh public key
```

In Sequel Pro it does look like this: [image: https://d.pr/i/Af7zUC]

Now I have a local app installed that is asking me for my MySQL credentials - when I enter my normal MySQL credentials from above this will not work. So I need to enter something (Server, Username, Password) in the app that is then establishing a connection to the database via the SSH connection as mentioned above. How do I do that? I tried it with:

```
ssh -L 1025:127.0.0.1:3306 -p 22 -l mysshuser -N dbhost.net
```

And then using `127.0.0.1:1025` in the app, but this doesn't do anything. Can you assist?

Comment: Try replacing `1025:127.0.0.1:3306` with `*:1025:127.0.0.1:3306` - This will make it listen on all interfaces. Maybe your local application tried a different interface or something. I've had that issue with a VNC application before.

Comment: @confetti Unfortunately this doesn't change anything. What else can this be? Once I type this line into my terminal, I do not see any response. Thats' correct, isn't it?

Comment: That's correct, `-N` does this, as you won't be actually sending anything over SSH, you just want to setup a port forwarding. You can omit the `-N` for testing, to see if anything goes wrong with keeping the ssh connection up.